# How do I restore the default sources.list file on Debian 11 (bullseye)?

Tags: debian, apt

I installed Debian 11 (Bullseye) onto a device with no internet. I used the "firmware CD" version of the ISO. I have configured the network, so I can do `ping 8.8.8.8`. I tried to run `sudo apt update`, but I discovered that there weren't any sources in the `sources.list` file (e.g., it was empty).

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340914/default-sources-list-on-debian-jessie-unsatisfiable-dependencies), but it is for Debian Jessie, not Bullseye.

I would also like `non-free` packages. How can I restore the default repositories, as if I had installed Debian with an internet connection?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find all the information about `sources.list` in [the official Debian wiki site](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList), specifically about your question under [Example sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

You can comment or delete the cdrom lines, since they are not useful anymore, and when executing `apt update` an error will be thrown.

Also comment out the `deb-src` lines unless you actually intend to download and compile source packages in the near future. Commenting them out halves the download time for `apt update`. Uncomment them if and when you want to recompile a package or examine its source code.

Comment: I think there is another simple way that doesn't involve browsing any wiki. As far as I remember, you can actually copy the `sources.list` from the iso image / CD / flash drive you used to install Debian in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

The original list already there just copy it

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list

$ sudo apt update
```

Comment: This solution does not require to know the original content, which depends on the version installed. It should be the accepted answer.